# JSP cant find request attributes set in Servlet when using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

The JSP does not recognize the data I give it with the servlet when I try to use JSTL. I can access the request attributes with Java code in the JSP but not using JSTL.

I am using a tomcat server. I tried changing some dependencies in the pom xml as I am using maven.
Right now I am using the 1.2 version of jstl.

from the pom.xml

```java
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
...
```

from the servlet

```java
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String data = "Some data, can be a String or a Javabean";
        request.setAttribute("data", data);
        request.setAttribute("userList", users);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/DisplayUsers.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
...
```

from the .jsp located in the webapp folder

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Alle gespeicherten Nutzer</title>
    <meta content = "text/html; charset = UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<% String name = request.getAttribute("data").toString(); //this works
out.print(""+name);
%>
<p>The data from servlet: ${data}</p> // THIS DOESN´T recognize data
```

Expected output: The data from servlet: Some data, can be a String or a Javabean
Actual output: The data from servlet: ${data}

Answer (score -1):

try this import for jsp
 place of <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
 this one <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>